# Click menu item to highlight in Backbone View

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, backbone.js

This is a simple problem for beginner but so far I haven't seen a solution that fits my need. Basically I got a simple menu with `ul` and `li`. There are 2 requirements:

**Req1:** When click on one, the `li` will get new class `.active`.

**Req2:** Menu items are dynamic, meaning I should be able to add or remove any menu item (by using some other button).

There are *2 ways* to do this:

**Method 1: Tranversing for each MenuView as MenuItem**

I have a MenuView with something like this

```
el:  $('li'),

events: {
  "click" : "highlight"
},

highlight: function(e) {
  thisParent = $(e.target).parent();
  thisParent.siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
  thisParent.addClass('active');
},
```

**Pro:** Easy. This is what I have now.

**Con:** Dependency on the html structure. What if it's changed to `div` instead with many layers.

**Method 2: One View for the MenuCollection**

Create a MenuItemCollection and use MenuView for that collection instead. The `el` for MenuView will be `ul` (instead of `li`). The HTML will look like this with separate `id`:

```
<ul>
    <li id="leftmenu-one">one</li>
    <li id="leftmenu-two">two</li>
    <li id="leftmenu-three">three</li>
</ul>
```

Then when a click event is detected, do 2 things:

**2a.** Remove all `.active` class in `ul li`

**2b.** Add `.active` class to the `e.target` DOM

**Pro:** Decoupling html design

**Con:** Little more code.

**QUESTION:** I think most people would say **Method 1** is bad. But is there method 3, 4, 5... that are better? How to handle the adding of new menu item?

Comment: Your code is a bit too reliant on the HTML structure. You shouldn't be doing that much DOM traversal in Backbone, because each View contains it's own HTML references. Instead of traversing the DOM, isolate the correct View and then have it handle the traversal on a smaller scale. A good way to do this is with Backbone Events.

Comment: @CoryDanielson Right I knew it and was checking other creative alternatives. Some reason your answer below was deleted. Can you repost? I'd love to keep it to study later.

Comment: Alright, I undeleted it. The only difference between mine and the other answer is that I don't have `active` as part of the model, because I don't really see that as business data that would be saved in any database.. it'd be a wasted column.. it's more of a UI/view thing. Because of that, I don't have change:active, and threw a custom event instead.

Comment: I also have `Req2` in there (Menu items are dynamic, meaning I should be able to add or remove any menu item (by using some other button).)

Comment: Thank you sir. You example has `MenuView` stored the entire `MenuItemView` in `activeButton`. Is there a memory concern even not much?

Comment: The other way around. Every menuItemView is in the menuView. Memory isn't an issue, everything is by reference

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a menu item model

```
    var MenuItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
        title: 'Default Title',
        isSelected: false
    });
```

and items collection, that would listen to any model selection change event

```
   var MenuItemCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: MenuItem,

        initialize: function() {
            this.on('change:isSelected', this.onSelectedChanged, this);
        },

        onSelectedChanged: function(model) {
            this.each(function(model) {
                if (model.get('isSelected') === true && !model.hasChanged('isSelected')) {
                    model.set({isSelected: false});
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

After that create a view each for menu item

```
   var MenuItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName:  'li',
        events: {
          'click' : 'highlight'
        },

        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this);
            this.model.on('change:isSelected', this.onSelectedChanged);
        },

        render: function() {
            this.$el.text(this.model.get('title'));
            return this;
        },

        onSelectedChanged: function() {
            if (this.model.get('isSelected') === true) {
                this.$el.addClass('active');
            }
            else {
                this.$el.removeClass('active');
            }
        },

        highlight: function() {
            this.model.set({isSelected: true});
        }
    });
```

and menu itself like

```
   var MenuView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName:  'ul',

        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this);
        },

        render: function() {
            this.collection.each(function(model) {
                var item = new MenuItemView({model: model});
                this.$el.append(item.render().el);
            }, this);

            return this;
        }
    });
```

Full working js fiddle with comments at http://jsfiddle.net/Kf3SS/

Comment: This is smart. So let me make sure I understand your logic: look like the idea is to leverage the `change` event of a model, right? The `click` event will set the model as `active` which triggered a `change` event to set `isSelected:false` of the old one using `hasChanged()` as the logic

Comment: Yes, in such a case it is rational to relay selection logic (which in fact is part of business logic for menu item) from view into models/collection, leaving view the opportunity to redraw itself accordingly to model state. The additional advantage is that you will preserve such behavior unrelated to items count or any other additional "onclick" item logic. Though generally in this case backbone implementation is loosing to pure jquery one in simplicity.

Comment: Great! I love the approach. It would be even better to use Marionette Collection View and collectionEvents.

Answer (score 1):

[**JSFiddle Demo w/ code comments**](http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/nNNBc/)

There's a bit of DOM traversal in your views that you most-likely want to avoid... because this example is so small, it's not going to ruin the user experience, but it's a best practice and all that good stuff.

I think this should be a good starting point/example for you.

#### Variable Setup

```
var MenuView
,   MenuItemView
,   MenuItemModel
,   menu          //MenuView Instance
,   menuItem      //MenuItemView Instance
;
```

#### MenuItemModel

```
MenuItemModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    'defaults': {
        'url': undefined
    ,   'text': undefined
    }
});
```

#### MenuView (<ul>)

```
MenuView = Backbone.View.extend({
    'tagName': 'ul'
,   'id': 'MenuView'
,   'menuItems': []
,   'activeButton': undefined
,   'initialize': function ( menuObjJSON, parent ) {
        var menuItem;

        for ( menuItemIndex in menuObjJSON ) {
            this.addMenuItem( new MenuItemModel(menuObjJSON[menuItemIndex]) )
        }
        this.render(parent);
    }
,   'render': function ( parent ) {
        $(parent).append(this.$el);
    }
,   'addMenuItem': function ( model ) {
    var menuItem = new MenuItemView({
            'model': model, 
            'parentElement': this.$el
        });
        menuItem.on('changeActive', this.setActiveButton, this);
        this.menuItems.push( menuItem );
        return menuItem;
}
,   'removeMenuItem': function ( identifier ) {
        var i, menuItem, length = this.menuItems.length, menuItemsCopy;
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if ( this.menuItems[i] ) {
                menuItemView = this.menuItems[i];
                if ( menuItemView.model.get('text').toLowerCase() === identifier.toLowerCase() 
                     || menuItemView.model.get('url').toLowerCase() === identifier.toLowerCase() ) 
                {
                    menuItemView.destroy();
                    debugger;
                    menuItemsEnd = this.menuItems.slice(i+1, length);
                    this.menuItems = [].concat(this.menuItems.slice(0,i), menuItemsEnd);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false; //if menu item not found
    }
,   'setActiveButton': function ( activeMenuItem ) {
        if ( this.activeButton ) {
            this.activeButton.removeHighlight();
        }
        this.activeButton = activeMenuItem;    
    }
});
```

#### MenuItemView (<li>)

```
MenuItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    'tagName': 'li'
,   'className': 'menuItem'
,   'events': { 
        'click a': 'highlight'
    }
,    'initialize': function ( options ) {
        this.render(options.model, options.parentElement);
    }
,   'render': function ( model, parentElement ) {
        this.$el.append("<a href='" + model.get('url')+ "'>" + model.get('text') + "</a>");
        parentElement.append(this.$el);
    }
,   'highlight': function ( event ) {
        if ( !this.$el.hasClass('active') ) {
            this.trigger('changeActive', this);
            this.$el.addClass('active');
        }
    }
,   'removeHighlight': function () {
        this.$el.removeClass('active');
    }
,   'destroy': function () {
        this.unbind('click a');
        this.remove(); //unbind from DOM, remove DOM events
    }
});
```

#### Menu Instantiation

```
menu = new MenuView([
    {'url': '#home',    'text': 'Home'}
,   {'url': '#catpics', 'text': 'Cat Pics'}
,   {'url': '#dogpics', 'text': 'Dog Pics'}
,   {'url': '#about',   'text': 'About Us'}
], $('body'));
```

#### Adding New Menu Items. (not the most practical example, but a starting point)

```
setTimeout(function(){
    menu.addMenuItem({'url': '#contact', 'text': 'Contact Us'});
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function(){
    menu.addMenuItem({'url': '#Login', 'text': 'Log In'});
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function(){
    menu.addMenuItem({'url': '#W3bm4573r', 'text': 'W3bm4573r'});
}, 3000);

setTimeout(function(){
    menu.addMenuItem({'url': '#something', 'text': 'Something'});
}, 4000);
```

#### Removing Menu Items  (not the most practical example, but a starting point)

```
setTimeout(function(){
    menu.removeMenuItem('#contact');
}, 5000);

setTimeout(function(){
    menu.removeMenuItem('about us');
}, 5000);

setTimeout(function(){
    menu.removeMenuItem('#SOMETHING');
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Sorry I have a hard time to understand the `click` event logic here. So when the `click` happens, `highlight` is called to add the `active` class. But how `changeActive` event ended up triggering `removeHighlight` for the old active menu item? I guess I don't understand the part in `setActiveButton`. Thanks.

Comment: The MenuView holds each of the MenuItemView's and listens to each ones changeActive event. When they trigger the changeActive event, they pass along `this` (the view itself) as a parameter. When the MenuView sees this event, it tells the `this.activeButton` to remove the highlight and then saves the new view (the one that triggered the event) to this.activeButton

Comment: menuItem: `this.trigger('changeActive', this);` .......... menu: `menuItem.on('changeActive', this.setActiveButton, this);` and `'setActiveButton': function ( activeMenuItem ) {}` .......... `this` from the menuItem gets passed into setActiveButton as activeMenuItem. The menu remove the highlight on the old one, and then overrides the new one in `this.activeButton`

Comment: http://aaronhardy.com/javascript/javascript-architecture-backbone-js-events/ (JavaScript Architecture: Backbone.js Events) Aaron Hardy
////////////////////
http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-fundamentals/#thebasics-events (Developing Backbone.js Applications - Events) Addy Osmani

Comment: Check the console log on the demo, it may help a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may be helpful to you. use this jquery

```
$("ul li").click(function() {
$("ul li").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
});
```

**[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/wgpUN/1/)**

Comment: Right I can use jQuery alone but the whole idea is to abstract the menu into View object.

Comment: In short, @HP. want the active item is based on the active view, not based on click event.